# No comparte los datos de $_SESSION en los demas documentos

Tags: php, session, sesiones

Buen día a todos. Estoy haciendo una página web en PHP donde involucra inicio de sesión. Todo iba bien hasta que mi página dejo de pasar los valores de $_SESSION al resto del sitio ("los valores se borran al pasar a otra página aunque tenga session_start() al inicio de mi código en cada pagina"), estoy buscando cual es el problema pero la verdad no se que es lo que esta pasando. Si alguien me puede dar un consejo oh mencionar otro método para las sesiones en php se los agradeceré mucho.

```
<?php session_start();

//omití la conexion a la base de datos para reducir codigo

$err = '';
if (isset($_POST['submitSession'])) {

    if (!empty($_POST['user'])) {
        $user = $_POST['user'];
        $user = trim(strtolower(filter_var($_POST['user'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));
    }else{
        $err = '*El usuario o la contrase単a son incorrectos';
    }

    if (!empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $password = hash('sha512', $password);
    }else{
        $err = '*El usuario o la contraseña son incorrectos';
    }

    $statement_user = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM data_users WHERE nombre = :usuario AND password = :password');
    $statement_user->execute(array(':usuario' => $user, ':password' => $password));
    $statement_user = $statement_user->fetch();
    
    if ($statement_user) {
        $_SESSION['nombre'] = $statement_user['nombre'];
        $_SESSION['max_download'] = $statement_user['max_download'];
    }else{
        $err = '*El usuario o la contraseña son incorrectos';
    }
}

 ?>
```

Comment: Se está enviando/recibiendo la información de sesión en los cookies en la comunicación cliente/servidor?

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Preguntar sin compartir el código relacionado equivale a ponernos a adivinar. Si nos muestras cómo estás intentando pasar los valores de $_SESSION, las cookies que reporta tu navegador y demás datos, será más fácil ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

Podrías revisar la `conf del server` link[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904105/php-sessions-default-timeout)

Puede ser que la sesión ha expirado y necesitas crear una nueva.

También sería bueno que incluyas un breve ejemplo de como estas iniciando la sesión y utilizándola.

Comment: Editare la pregunta para que se vea como introduzco la sesión, pero no creo que sea eso, quite esa parte del código e introduje los datos de manera manual en $_SESSION y los mande a imprimir en otro documento y no se veían